# Why do types referenced outside of a namespace need to be fully qualified?

Tags: c#

Given the following code snippet:

```
using System;

using Foo = System.Int32;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the "System." from in front of Int32 in my declaration for the "Foo" type alias, I get a compiler error. Despite the fact that I'm using the System namespace at the top of the file, the compiler can't find an unqualified "Int32" type.

Why is that?

Comment: It's not "types" outside of a namespace. It's only on using alias declarations. `class Program { static void Main(String[] args) { Int32 x = 0; } }` outside of a namespace block works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because the C# specification says that it must be.  More specifically, section 9.4.1 in the C# specification says:

> The order in which using-alias-directives are written has no significance, and resolution of the namespace-or-type-name referenced by a using-alias-directive is not affected by the using-alias-directive itself or by other using-directives in the immediately containing compilation unit or namespace body. In other words, the namespace-or-type-name of a using-alias-directive is resolved as if the immediately containing compilation unit or namespace body had no using-directives. A using-alias-directive may however be affected by extern-alias-directives in the immediately containing compilation unit or namespace body.

Since order doesn't matter, the `using System;` has no effect on the using-alias-directive.  The specific section that matters is: "*the namespace-or-type-name of a using-alias-directive is resolved as if the immediately containing compilation unit or namespace body had no using-directives*".

Comment: This also explains why "using Bar = System.Collections.Generic.List<Foo>;" on the very next line doesn't work either. Thanks!

Comment: @Matt: You're welcome.  When in doubt, look it up in the spec ;)

Answer (score 6):

Because using statements are not processed in any particular order.  The compiler doesn't know to process the first line before the second.

Answer (score 4):

The [spec (9.3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664764%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) says:

> The scope of a using-directive extends over the namespace-member-declarations of its immediately containing compilation unit or namespace body. The scope of a using-directive specifically does not include its peer using-directives. Thus, peer using-directives do not affect each other, and the order in which they are written is insignificant.

Move your last `using` inside the namespace block and it will work.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    using Foo = Int32;
```

Comment: I know it works inside the namespace block - I was just curious as to why. Is it in the spec somewhere?

Comment: The addition of a quote from the spec is welcome, @Slaks, but I think I'll have to give the answer to Reed for posting that text first. +1 though!